# Ubuntu docker image doesn't contain any /dev/sdX block devices?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, device

On normal linux machine or VM, "ls /dev" will show a lot of sdX or hdX hard disk information.

But today I just tried latest docker and ubuntu image. ls shows this:

```
console  core  fd  full  mqueue  null  ptmx  pts  random  shm  stderr  stdin  stdout  tty  urandom  zero
```

I don't see anything called sdX or hdX.

Why is this? How docker ubuntu store anything without having a /dev/sdX?

Comment: Docker provides it with a filesystem. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/

Comment: Docker is a container, not a computer, why would it even have harddisks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker doesn't create virtual machines, it creates containers to run an application in an isolated space. Including physical hardware devices would allow those applications to escape from the container isolation, so they are not provided by default. You can include specific devices inside the container with the `docker run --device ...` cli flag, and you will most likely need to include `--privileged` give the root user back various capabilities that are removed. None of this is recommended for running untrusted containers.